# Error with Python crypto on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyopenssl

I'm running a basic crypto program written in Python, and while it worked fine on OS X, I cannot get it to run on Windows (either in 3.6/Anaconda that was installed with VS 2017 when I checked in the setup that I wanted Python installed, and in a standalone 3.4 binary install).

Like individually each import statement works in the interpreter, but as a whole this program doesn't work

```
from hashlib import sha256

from pbkdf2_ctypes import *
import hmac
import hashlib
import binascii
from os import urandom
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import getpass

masterpassword = "thisisamasterpassword"
salt = urandom(16) 
masterpassword = pbkdf2_hex(masterpassword.encode('utf-8'), salt)
password = masterpassword.decode()
salt = binascii.hexlify(salt)
salt = salt.decode()

print(masterpassword)
```

The result is:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>py -3.4 masterpassword.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pbkdf2_ctypes.py", line 127, in <module>
    raise OSError('Library not found')
OSError: Library not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "masterpassword.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pbkdf2_ctypes import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pbkdf2_ctypes.py", line 153, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Cannot find a compatible cryptographic library '
ImportError: Cannot find a compatible cryptographic library on your system
```

I also installed both an OpenSSL binary (https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and made sure it was running under Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to guess this code never worked on a Windows-64bit machine.  The error that is raised comes from `pbkdf2_ctypes` in the logic to search for the crypto library; and I think it was an accidental (although sensible) assumption that libeay64.dll will be installed on 64-bit systems and libeay32.dll for 32-bit systems:

```
if system == 'Windows':
    if platform.architecture()[0] == '64bit':
        libname = ctypes.util.find_library('libeay64') # <--- This does not exist even on 64bit machines ... :)
        if not libname:
            raise OSError('Library not found')
        crypto = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
    else:
        libname = ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')
        if not libname:
            raise OSError('Library libeay32 not found.')
```

You can try to contact someone from Glisco, but I don't think they're around anymore as their public code base has gone quite for a couple years now.

**To get you going**

You can either:

1. run `ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')` in python and see where your library is.  Then copy libeay32.dll to libeay64.dll in the same folder.  This shouldn't cause any problems because you're duplicating a file that no other program is aware of.
2. Remove `from pbkdf2_ctypes import *`, and add these functions to your code that were ripped from pbkdf2_ctypes.

   import ctypes
   import ctypes.util

   libname = ctypes.util.find_library('libeay32')
   crypto = ctypes.CDLL(libname)

   def _openssl_hashlib_to_crypto_map_get(hashfunc):
       hashlib_to_crypto_map = {hashlib.md5: crypto.EVP_md5,
                                hashlib.sha1: crypto.EVP_sha1,
                                hashlib.sha256: crypto.EVP_sha256,
                                hashlib.sha224: crypto.EVP_sha224,
                                hashlib.sha384: crypto.EVP_sha384,
                                hashlib.sha512: crypto.EVP_sha512}
       crypto_hashfunc = hashlib_to_crypto_map.get(hashfunc)
       if crypto_hashfunc is None:
           raise ValueError('Unkwnown digest %s' % hashfunc)
       crypto_hashfunc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
       return crypto_hashfunc()

   def _openssl_pbkdf2(data, salt, iterations, digest, keylen):
       """OpenSSL compatibile wrapper
       """
       c_hashfunc = ctypes.c_void_p(_openssl_hashlib_to_crypto_map_get(digest))

   ```
   c_pass = ctypes.c_char_p(data)
   c_passlen = ctypes.c_int(len(data))
   c_salt = ctypes.c_char_p(salt)
   c_saltlen = ctypes.c_int(len(salt))
   c_iter = ctypes.c_int(iterations)
   c_keylen = ctypes.c_int(keylen)
   c_buff = ctypes.create_string_buffer(keylen)

   crypto.PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int,
                                    ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int,
                                    ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p,
                                    ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p]

   crypto.PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.restype = ctypes.c_int
   err = crypto.PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(c_pass, c_passlen,
                       c_salt, c_saltlen,
                       c_iter,
                       c_hashfunc,
                       c_keylen,
                       c_buff)
   return (err, c_buff)
   ```

   def pkcs5_pbkdf2_hmac(data, salt, iterations=1000, keylen=24, hashfunc=None):
       if hashfunc is None:
           hashfunc = hashlib.sha1
       err, c_buff = _openssl_pbkdf2(data, salt, iterations, hashfunc, keylen)

   ```
   if err == 0:
       raise ValueError('wrong parameters')
   return c_buff.raw[:keylen]
   ```

   def pbkdf2_hex(data, salt, iterations=1000, keylen=24, hashfunc=None):
       return binascii.hexlify(pkcs5_pbkdf2_hmac(data, salt, iterations, keylen, hashfunc))

Comment: Thank you!  I followed your first (easier, I guess) solution of copying libeay32 to a new libeay64, which happened to be in C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\Library\bin for me (running the 3.6 that came with VS 2017). I also noticed that test earlier where it was failing, but I don't feel nearly so confident digging into that code :(